# Create eml file in memory without saving it on disk

Tags: c#, web-applications, eml

I'm working with C# on Windows servers for a web application stored on the IIS Server.

I would like to create an eml file from :

- an html content (string)
- some attachments that are loaded in memory
- a string subject
- string recipients
- string sender

The main problem is that **I am not allowed to store files on the host server** (not even in a temporary directory or if I delete them after).

I saw many threads explaining [how to create an eml file with the help of SmtpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264672/how-to-save-mailmessage-object-to-disk-as-eml-or-msg-file). But we always need to use a directory to save the file.

Do someone knows a way to do that ? Or to create a directory in memory ([which seems undoable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149906/create-a-directory-in-memory)) ?

Thanks for everyone who will read me

[EDIT]
Using jstedfast's answer below and the [Mime documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Frequently-Asked-Questions.htm#CreateAttachments), I could figure a way. Here is a POC in case someone needs it later.

```
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey", "joey@friends.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com"));
        message.Subject = "How you doin?";

        var builder = new BodyBuilder();

        // Set the plain-text version of the message text
        builder.TextBody = @"Hey Alice,

What are you up to this weekend? Monica is throwing one of her parties on
Saturday and I was hoping you could make it.

Will you be my +1?

-- Joey
";

        // We may also want to attach a calendar event for Monica's party...
        builder.Attachments.Add("test.pdf", attachmentByteArray);

        // Now we just need to set the message body and we're done
        message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            message.WriteTo(memory);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit).

You can write the MimeMessage objects to any type of stream that you want, including a MemoryStream.

Comment: Thanks I will look at this